# how to use object keys in handlebars?

Tags: html, object, handlebars.js

I am new to javascript and I have this problem I can't seem to solve. I tried watching videos and even came here for answer but the ones I found didn't make any sense to me. So imagine you are helping an idiot :). Anyways I am fetching an object and this is what I have.

```
{
  "Global Quote": {
    "01. symbol": "A",
    "02. open": "84.7000",
    "03. high": "85.8400",
    "04. low": "83.4500",
    "05. price": "85.1300",
    "06. volume": "2908808",
    "07. latest trading day": "2020-02-19",
    "08. previous close": "84.7900",
    "09. change": "0.3400",
    "10. change percent": "0.4010%"
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to display it with handlebars.

This is my handlebars template:

```
<h1>Stock Viewer</h1>
symbol: <span class="symbol">{{symbol}}</span><br>
date: <span class="date">{{price}}</span><br>
price: <span class="price">{{date}}</span>
```

I can't seem to get the data out of the object. I can only generate part of the code that is not a variable.

And also I am not sure how this will look when I post the question so I apologize in advance if it is messy.
Thanks!

Comment: As you are new to JavaScript, I recommend that you learn to develop solutions with JavaScript in the first place, because all libraries such as AngularJS, jQuery, Handlebars, among others, are created with JavaScript. It can generate confusion in general, if you decide to start from scratch with a library. But if you already have the knowledge of JavaScript in the first place, you can use any library very easily. You can even create your own libraries with JavaScript. Good luck.

Comment: I was able to get the data to display using innerText and vanilla JavaScript but converting it to handlebars is much harder for me. My guess is I am doing something wrong with the object. My keys have spaces and I tried things like: {{01. symbol}}, {{[01. symbol]}}, {{{01. symbol}}}, {{'01. symbol'}}, {{['01. symbol']}}. Nothing works :(

Answer (score 0):

Your keys (e.g. `04. low`) contain spaces and dots, both of which are to be avoided if possible in JavaScript (object property names - keys - can be any string, but both spaces and dots complicate things a lot, as do most chars other than alphanumeric ones, for various reasons), and definitely in Handlebars. You will save yourself a lot of pain if you are able to switch to alphanumeric keys.